# Pattern variable in RegExp doesn't work with specifiers

Tags: javascript, regex

The following code writes "response" as expected:

```
var str = "Would you like to have responses";
var pattern = "Response";
document.write(str.match(new RegExp(pattern,'gi')));
```

but when I add a specifier like `\b`, the following writes "null":

```
var str = "Would you like to have responses";
var pattern = "\bResponse";
document.write(str.match(new RegExp(pattern,'gi')));
```

How can I make it work?

---

Interestingly, both of the following works

```
document.write(str.match(new RegExp(/Response/gi)));
document.write(str.match(new RegExp(/\bResponse/gi)));
```

but I want to use `new RegExp(pattern,modifiers);` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backslash has a special meaning in a string, it's the escape character. When you want to create a Regular expression from a string, backslashes has to be escaped.

In the case when the escaped characters have the same meaning, you're not going to notice it:

```
 '\n'.match('\n');
 '\n'.match('\\n');
```

both work. However, `\b` does not have such a meaning in a string.
`new RegExp("\bResponse");` becomes `/Response/` (`\b` is a backspace character, which does not represent a visible character). When an escape does not have a special meaning, the backslash is dropped.

Comment: it actually becomes `/\u0008Response/` `"\b"` is the backspace character [`U+0008`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0008/index.htm)

Comment: @Esailija Thanks, my last line was missing some words :p

Comment: So, to put it simply I have to escape `\b` like `var pattern = "\\bResponse";` :)

Comment: @sevenkul Yes. But I recommend to use RegExp litererals, `/\bResponse/gi` instead of the constructor, unless the regexp is constructed dynamically.